# Filter by name after applying a filter that changes characters

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've come across a situation where I need to filter elements created by the 'ng-repeat' directive, but I've applied a custom filter that swaps one character by another and vice versa, for each created element.

Then, if I search for the new character that was swapped, the filter won't find it - unless I search for the old one.

**How do I apply this input filter after using my custom filter which swaps characters?**

In my custom filter **brNumber**, **dots** are swapped by **commas** and vice-versa, so if I search for a dot the filter will find only the ones with comma.

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lcafzuc/2/)**

**< HTML >**

```
<div 
ng-app="myApp" 
ng-init="
    person=
    [
        {firstName:'Johnny',lastName:'Dowy'},
        {firstName:'Homem,25',lastName:'Cueca,Suja'},                
        {firstName:'Alleria.Donna',lastName:'Windrunner'}
    ];"
>

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName">
<br />
The persons's objects have: | <span ng-repeat="i in person | orderBy: 'firstName' | filter:firstName">{{ ( i.firstName + ' ' + i.lastName ) | brNumber }} | </span>
```

**{ Javascript.js }**

```
app.filter( 'brNumber', function()
{
    return function( text )
    {
        string = text.toString();        
        returnString = '';

        for ( i = 0; i < string.length; i++ )
        {
            returnString += string[i] ===  ',' ? '.' :
            (
                string[i] === '.' ? ',' : string[i]
            );
        }

        return returnString;
    }
});
```

Comment: I am not sure if what you are doing is correct. You are not modifying your model i.e person, hence the filter still applying on the original model. You can just iterate over the person object once more to confirm the values currently present in your model. All you need to do is update your model.

Comment: Thanks, but could you evaluate this, if possible? I'm new to Angular and I'm working with something based on what I posted. It will basically get a raw price value from a database and show different money values on the front-end based on localization and exchange rate of the country.

Comment: My guess would be that you are returning a new string from the query filter rather than modifying the original person object. Thats where the issue is. I will prefer if you give it a shot first, rather than me posting the answer. If you are unable to do it, I will help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap a filtered value in same function as a filter in view. Check this https://jsfiddle.net/5Lcafzuc/3/

```
/// wrap filter argument in function
ng-repeat="i in person | orderBy: 'firstName' | filter: replace(firstName)"

/// add function in scope and use it in display filter
var replace = function(text) {        
         if(!text) {
           return false;
         }         

         if(text.indexOf(".") >= 0) {
           text = text.replace(".", ",");
         } else if(text.indexOf(",") >=0) {
           text = text.replace(",", ".");
         }

         return text;
      }

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {    
    $scope.replace = replace;
});

app.filter( 'brNumber', function() {
    return function(text) {        
         return replace(text);
    }
});
```